# Make all instances of UINavigationBar titles lowercase without subclassing?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Some titles in this iOS app are defined in the storyboard. Some of the titles are being set programmatically. Is there a simple way (Obj-C categories maybe?) to make all the titles lowercase without subclassing?

Comment: This is exactly why you should subclass.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with a bit of objective-c magic, using [method_exchangeImplementations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) (AKA "Method Swizzling")

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface UINavigationItem (New)
@end

@implementation UINavigationItem (New)

- (void)setTitleLower:(NSString *)title {
    [self setTitleLower:[title lowercaseString]];
}

+ (void)load {
    method_exchangeImplementations(class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(setTitle:)), class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(setTitleLower:)));
}

@end
```

Now each call to `someNavItem.title = @"Whatever"` (`[UINavigationItem setTitle:(NSString*)title]`) should go through setTitleLower, which in turn also calls the original `setTitle` with a minor modification, lowercasing the title.

I would avoid having to implement such a category just for the sake of lower-casing all titles for each `UINavigationItem`. I guess you're experimenting categories.